# AVL tree rotation error

Tags: tree, rotation, pascal

I've programmed most of an AVL tree in pascal, and when I try to rotate a node it doesnt work as I intend it to.

Lets say I insert 50 20 10 in this order, my procedure is given the node 50, and after doing a rotation it should give back the node 20 with the child nodes, but it returns the 50 instead. Im not sure if its because im not allowed to use as a parameter a node and change its children or something.

Im pretty confused so any help will be really welcome. I give the code which i use to rotate a node bellow, and inside the rotation procedure if i check the nodes by their value and the childre value, the node 20 has 10 and 50 as his children, so the rotation itself works, the problem seems to be that the procedure does not give me back the node with 20 as the parent one.

```
      50                      20
   20            to        10    50     but instead returns only    50
10
```

This is the routine used to rotate the node

```
procedure balancear(var a:arbol); // balancea el arbol dado
var aux,aux2:arbol;

   procedure rotationL; 
   begin
     aux:=a^.left^.right;
     aux2:=a^.left;
     a^.left^.right:=a;
     a^.left:=aux;
     a:=aux2;
   end


begin
     if a<>nil then
     begin
         if nivel(a^.left)-nivel(a^.right) > 1 then rotationL
         else if nivel(a^.left)-nivel(a^.right) < -1 then rotationR;
     end;
end;
```

nivel is a function which returns the level depth of the tree, which i use to check if a tree node is not balanced.

Thanks for your time folks.

P.S. im only using rotationL atm, i have rotationR and everything done but for askign purposes i just copied this. If someone else needs something else to check it out just say so.

Answer (score 0):

Ok all i needed to do was to save the parent pointer and reassign the child, in case anyone is interested.